# How does break statement work?

Tags: c, break

If i write break statement in for loop then will variable be updated and then for loop exits,or after just excecution of break statement for loop exits?
for e.g

```
for(i=0;i<100;i++){
//do something something
if(i==50){
break;
}
```

what will be the value of i after for loop exit?

Comment: Note: there is a `}` missing.

Comment: Actually, any effort is missing...Or I am too advanced =)

Comment: why don't you just add a printf after the loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value will be 50.

The `for` loop can be described in general terms like this:

```
for(INIT; CONDITION; UPDATE)
  BODY
```

and it can be replaced with the equivalent `while` loop, like this:

```
INIT
while(CONDITION)
{
  BODY
  UPDATE
}
```

So, since your `break` is in the `BODY`, the `UPDATE` is not run, and the value `50` remains.

Answer (score 5):

When the break statement is encountered inside a loop, the loop is immediately terminated and program control resumes at the next statement following the loop.It can be used to terminate a case in the switch statement

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If loop ready to exit by the break statement , that mean the **i** value should be equal to the condition .

```
if(i==50);
```

> i Will be 50

...